# 'ActiveRecord::Core::ClassMethods.find' call is deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rubymine

I'm using RubyMine 2016.1 and when I use the `find(id)` method of ActiveRecord it shows me this deprecation warning: 'ActiveRecord::Core::ClassMethods.find' call is deprecated, however, in the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0-active-record), find with primary key is not deprecated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This seems to be a **known bug** in Rubymine 2016.1. You can track [this bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-17979) if you like and you can safely ignore this deprecation warning.

**Update:** the bug seems to be **fixed now** in the Rubymine 2016.1.1 security release. The IDE no longer annotates this statement as deprecated.