# assert_select is flagged as deprecated in RubyMine 2016.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubymine, minitest

I recently upgraded to RubyMine 2016.1, and have noticed that the `assert_select` method in minitest is marked as deprecated. 
Here is the warning I get,

```
'Rails::Dom::Testing::Assertions::SelectorAssertions.assert_select' call is deprecated less... (⌘F1) 

 This inspection warns about features that were deprecated in Rails 3.0 and will be removed in future versions.
```

Is this true? I can't find any clear information to corroborate this. Can anyone clarify if this is just a bug in RubyMine, or if it is actually being deprecated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `assert_select` is actually not deprecated. This seems to be a bug in Rubymine 2016.1, similar to the [`Model.find` deprecation warning bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36480425/activerecordcoreclassmethods-find-call-is-deprecated). Someone even [referenced](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-17979#comment=27-1402295) this problem it in the same issue in the bug tracker.

So, although I could not find any more relevant links to prove, I guess it is the same bug which is supposed to be fixed in the Rubymine 2016.1.2 release later this year.

**Update:** the bug seems to be fixed now in the Rubymine 2016.1.1 security release. The IDE no longer annotates this statement as deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for this, I hadn't noticed the `Model.find` bug yet.